# Codeigniter Index file issue

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have already worked in the CI. But this time when i remove the index file. I am getting 404 error. But i did everything correctly. Here is the settings i have done.

```
.htaccess
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|files\/images|files\/javascripts|files\/stylesheets|files\/swf|files\/upload)
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /qrout/index.php/$1 [L]

   Config File
   $config['base_url']  = 'http://webscarlets.in/projects/';
   $config['index_page']   = '';
```

I hope above settings are all correct. And i have tried added this 'qrout' folder in the base url still it's not working

Here is the website link
http://webscarlets.in/projects/qrout/welcome

Kindly guide me to solve this issue.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Did U set `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';` in config ?

Comment: No it was in 'AUTO' mode

Comment: Try with `'REQUEST_URI'`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this condition .....ITs working for me

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your rewrite condition is targeting js files and things like that. Those files don't need the index.php in their path. Only your Codeigniter files will.

I'd rework that conditional statement.